# ¿Se puede elegir el tamaño o grosor de un text-decoration en CSS?

Tags: html, css, web

hoy me plantee una duda que al investigar no he podido dar con la respuesta.
¿Es acaso posible en CSS elegir el tamaño de un underline o un overline agregado con text-decoration?

```css
#primerParrafo{
color: #fffff;
font-size: 150%;
font-family: "pineapple";
text-decoration: underline;  /*<<<-- aquí radica mi duda con el underline */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la propiedad: `text-decoration-thickness`. tiene la función de especificar el grosor del text-decoration underline, line-through, o overline.

Un ejemplo de su utilización sería:

```
#text {
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  text-decoration-thickness: 2px; <--- grosor especificado
}
```

Te comparto [información extra](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-decoration-thickness/) (en inglés) que encontré sobre la propiedad por si te es de ayuda.

Comment: Días buscando una solucion!! grande crack!

Comment: @WilmerAnzola De nada hermano! Si solucionó tu pregunta considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada:) Buen dia

Answer (score 0):

lo que puedes hacer es usar border:

```
#primerParrafo{
  color: #fffff;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-family: "pineapple";
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Puedes cambiar el "1px" al grosor que deseas, e incluso el color del borde

Comment: En un párrafo con muchas líneas, el borde sólo se verá en la última. Esto no es lo que preguntó el OP

Answer (score 0):

Tenía la idea de que era una propiedad estática e inherente a la fuente usada, pero resulta que no es así.

Se puede controlar el grosor de la linea de `underline` u `overline` usando la propiedad CSS: [`text-decoration-thickness`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-thickness) que es una propiedad relativamente nueva.

Por ejemplo:

```css
.thick {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-thickness: 3px;
}
```

```html
<p class="thick">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver tu duda.

Comment: Ya me estaba dando por rendido, ya que todos me decian que usara mejor border o un shadow para realizar la linea!! Gracias crack! <3